# Read file into nested linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, nested

I am trying to read a test file and write it into a nested linked list and then print it out.

I am trying to read the file below and if the `vlanID` (second column) is not present in the `vlan_tuple` linked list then I add it to the list, and if it is present I add the interface (first column) to the nested list `vlan_if_list`. My issue is that the code seems to overwrite the `vlanID` list when I try to add a new entry to `vlanID`. Hope I have included enough information here.

**File to be read**

```
    eth1 2
    eth2 1
    eth3 2
    eth4 1
    eth5 2
```

**Nested linked list**

```
    /* Container for VID Table */
    struct vid_addr_tuple
    {
        char eth_name[ETH_ADDR_LEN];    // Port of Acquisition
        char vid_addr[VID_ADDR_LEN];    // VID Address.
        time_t last_updated;        // last updated time
        int port_status;        // Port Type i.e. PVID, MTP
        int isNew;
        struct vid_addr_tuple *next;
        uint8_t path_cost;      // VID path cost.
        struct ether_addr mac;
        int membership;         // Membership PRIMARY, SECONDARY, TERTIARY
    };
```

**Main linked list**

```
    /* Container for VLAN Table */
    struct vlan_tuple {
        int vlanID;
        struct vlan_if_list *vlan_if;
        struct vid_addr_tuple *vid;
        struct child_pvid_tuple *cpvid;
        struct local_bcast_tuple *local;
        struct vlan_tuple *next;
    };
```

**Function to read file**

```
    bool read_vlan_if_list(int vlanID) // This vlanID parameter is not used
    {
    printf("read_vlan_if_list\n");
    struct vlan_tuple *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct vlan_tuple));
    temp->next = NULL;
    vlan_tuple_head = temp;
    vlan_if_head = temp->vlan_if;

     // AK - Read VLAN config file
     char intName[10]; // Interface name from file
     int intVlan; // Interface VLAN from file
     int checkVlan = 1;
     FILE * pFile; // File pointer
     pFile = fopen ("./vlan.conf","r");

     if (pFile == NULL)
     {
           //perror("ERROR: Unable to open vlan.conf\n");
           return false  ;
     } else {
         temp->vlanID = 0;
         printf("-- vlanID set to 0\n");
         while (fscanf (pFile,"%s %d",intName,&intVlan) != EOF)
         {
           temp = vlan_tuple_head;
           printf("-- Start vlanID : %d \n", temp->vlanID);
           int flag = 0;
           //do
           for (temp = vlan_tuple_head; temp->vlanID != 0; temp = temp->next)
           {
           // Add interface to VLAN if already present
              vlanID = temp->vlanID;
              printf("vlanID and intVlan : %d %d\n", vlanID, intVlan);
              if (intVlan == vlanID)
              {
                //temp->vlan_if = malloc(sizeof(struct vlan_if_list));
                strcpy(temp->vlan_if->if_name,intName);
                printf("if %s : %s\n", temp->vlan_if->if_name,intName);
                temp->vlan_if->next = malloc(sizeof(struct vlan_if_list));
                temp->vlan_if = temp->vlan_if->next;
                temp->vlan_if->next = NULL;
              }

                printf("%d\n",temp->vlanID);
                int flag = 1;
                printf("flag1 : %d\n", flag);
           }
           printf("flag2 : %d\n", flag);
           if (flag == 0)
           {


             temp->vlanID = intVlan; //Add new VLAN
             printf("New VLAN %d added\n", temp->vlanID);
             temp->vlan_if = malloc(sizeof(struct vlan_if_list));
             strcpy(temp->vlan_if->if_name,intName);
             printf("else If %s added\n", temp->vlan_if->if_name);

           }
           printf("End vlanID : %d \n", temp->vlanID);

           //Point to next vlan_tuple pointer to continue while loop
           temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct vlan_tuple));
           temp = temp->next;
           temp->vlanID = 0;
           temp->next = NULL;
           printf("Point to next\n");
         }
         printf("a\n");
       }
       printf("b\n");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `temp = malloc(sizeof(struct vlan_tuple));` allocate an *uninitialized pointer* for `temp->vlan_if;`, therefore you assign an indeterminate value with `vlan_if_head = temp->vlan_if;` You need to allocate as you were attempting to do with `//temp->vlan_if = malloc(sizeof(struct vlan_if_list));`, otherwise you just keep assigning to the same address over-and-over again.

Comment: `temp = vlan_tuple_head;` this reassigns `temp` and you lose contact with the previously allocated memory.